# RDF Triple Visualizer - ARC2

Tags: php, graph, rdf, triplestore

Hi there does anyone know of any good software for visualising an rdf triple store as an actual graph?  I am using an arc2 triplestore and have already tried the visualizer plug in that is available from semasols site but I cant get it to work: I keep getting theis error: XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: data:image/svg+xml;base64,
Line Number 1, Column 1:

I think that the software (Graphviz) isnt linking up with the store somehow but cant work it out.

I would have assumed that there would be some sort of api that you could use for this sort of thing but I cant find anything.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The XML parsing error could be due to an empty response. If this is the case, you could simply add a non-xml header, so that your browser doesn't try parse the file as XML (failing):

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```